# Getting the `certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)` erro with Mechanize object

Tags: ruby, ssl, windows-xp, ssl-certificate, mechanize

For the below code got `certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)` :

***CODE***

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new

#{|a| a.ssl_version, a.verify_mode = 'SSLv3', OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE}

agent.set_proxy('3.209.30.25', 80)
agent.ssl_version='SSLv3'
agent.verify_mode= OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER

page = agent.get "https://gegsltraining.aravo.com/"
```

***Error***

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-http-persistent-2.8/lib/net/http/persist
ent/ssl_reuse.rb:70:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 rea
d server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

***EDIT***

I just modified code as follows:

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new
#{|a| a.ssl_version, a.verify_mode = 'SSLv3', OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE}
agent.set_proxy('3.209.30.25', 80)
agent.ssl_version='SSLv3'
cert_store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
cert_store.add_file 'E:\WIPData\Ruby\Scripts\cacert.pem'
agent.cert_store = cert_store
agent.verify_mode= OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER (tried OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE none of them going good)
```

***New Error***

```
E:\WIPData\Ruby\Scripts>mechanizev1.rb
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2632:in `error!': 500 "Internal Server Err
or" (Net::HTTPFatalError)
```

How to be done that certification verification successfully? help me.

Comment: Please help me here, my code got stuck due to the issue!

Comment: You seem to be having many problems with the most basic concepts. Have you considered hiring someone to help you?

Comment: I thought the community can be a good option,where I can have multiple people who has faced the same issue. He might be helpful for me. Because these are really some serious problems,for which none of the code runs.

Comment: +1 @pguardiario, Not only many basic problems, but I suspect under multiple personalities too.

Answer (score 0):

Just set your mechanize agent object.http.ca_file  to point to this file.

```
agent.agent.http.ca_file = '/etc/ssl/certs/curl-ca-bundle.crt'
```

Otherway to do this, is to save the curl-ca-bundle.crt in app lib directory
and then set

```
agent.agent.http.ca_file = 'lib/curl-ca-bundle.crt'
```

Comment: Do you mean to say the `C:\Ruby193\lib`? I am using `windows-XP`