# Google Trends Quota Limit

Tags: google-api, limit, quota

I'm trying to pull data from Google trends and got a "You have reached your daily limit" error after only 2 tries.

Is there any way to go around this? I know Google API projects have special quota limits but Google Trends doesn't have an API. I also read that we may need to pass it a cookie file so that it seems like I'm logged in. Has anyone faced this issue before?

Answer (score 5):

I'm struggling with the same issue!
From your question I can't figure out what stage have you achieved...
But here is the solution that I've found:

1. You should emulate browser with cookies.
   I think the best way to do it is to use [**Mechanize**](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) library.
2. At first your program should "login" using GET request to "https://accounts.google.com/Login?hl=en"
3. Immediately after that you can access some other personal resources, **but not google trends!**
4. After some *significant* time you can successfully get google trends data as CSV.
5. I still have not discovered the exact time period, but it is more than 10 minutes and less than several hours :). That is why saving your cookies for latter use is a good idea!

Few more tips:

- If you are developing using python / ruby under Windows do not forget to set up CA ROOT certificates package for OpenSSL library. Otherwise HTTPS connection will fail and you won't login! See [Getting the `certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)` erro with Mechanize object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474937/getting-the-certificate-verify-failed-opensslsslsslerror-erro-with-mecha)
- I recommend you to save cookies to external file at program shutdown. And restoring them at startup.
- Do not forget to allow redirects, because Google is using redirects all the time.

Ruby code example:

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'logger'
begin
  agent = Mechanize.new { |a|
    a.user_agent = 'Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16'

    cert_store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
    cert_store.add_file 'cacert.pem'
    a.cert_store = cert_store

    a.log = Logger.new('mech.log')

    if File.file?('mech.cookies')
      cookies = Mechanize::CookieJar.new
      cookies.load('mech.cookies')
      a.cookie_jar = cookies
    end

    a.open_timeout = 5
    a.read_timeout = 6
    a.keep_alive   = true
    a.redirect_ok  = true
  }

  LOGIN_URL = "https://accounts.google.com/Login?hl=en&continue=http://www.google.com/trends/"
  login_page = agent.get(LOGIN_URL)
  login_form = login_page.forms.first
  login_form.Email = *
  login_form.Passwd = *
  login_response_page = agent.submit(login_form)

  page = agent.get(url)

  # DO SOME TRENDS REQUESTS AFTER SIGNIFICANT PERIOD OF TIME

ensure
  if agent
    agent.cookie_jar.save('mech.cookies')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably disabled your cookies, which makes Google Trends think you're a robot

Comment: Worked for me - I'd left adblock turned on which did it. Disable it on the domain and it's fine.

Answer (score 3):

I think I have found a way to solve the problem. Just make sure that you call the Google Trends API with the cookie `PREF`. That is you don't need to login the Google account. Of course, you don't need to emulate browser. The cookie `PREF` is just enough.

OK. Where the cookie `PREF` comes from? It is very easy. Just open the browser, and login in your Google account. Finally, look up the cookie `PREF` under the Google website, it is just under the domain `www.google.com`.Then copy the value of the cookie `PREF` to your program or script. That's all.

I have called the Google Trends API hundreds of times in several seconds by this way. Good Luck to you!

Comment: can you tell me how to use it in java??

Comment: I used the cookie `NID` and it worked for me for at least 30 requests in a minute, for at least 5 minutes (haven't stress tested yet)

Answer (score -6):

I found this paper about prevention or just a Zeta-Jones effect in google Trends, it was so useable: 
G Fond, A Gamanb, E Haffenb, P Llorca. ["Google Trends: ready for real-time suicide prevention or just a Zeta-Jones effect ?."](http://ijcncs.org/published/volume3/issue1/p1_3-1.pdf) International Journal of Computer Networks and Communications Security 3, no. 1 (2015): 1-5.

Comment: Can you explain how this answers the OP's question?