# python urllib.requst 'You have reached your quota limit. Please try again later' in google trends

Tags: python-3.x, request, urllib

```
 import urllib
 def getUrl():
    url = 'https://www.google.ie/trends/fetchComponent?hl=en-AU&q=boston%20celtics&date=now%201-d&cmpt=q&tz=Etc%2FGMT-1&tz=Etc%2FGMT-1&content=1&cid=RISING_ENTITIES_0_0&cat=0-20'
    headers = {}
    headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17"   
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers = headers)
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    respData = resp.read().decode('utf-8')
    print(respData)
    print('......................................................')

timeframe = {'day':'d','week':'w'}
team=['boston celtics','Houston Rockets','Cleveland Cavaliers','Golden State Warriors']
for i in team:
    getUrl(i,timeframe['day'])
```

I am try to crawl data from google(https://www.google.ie/trends/fetchComponent?hl=en-AU&q=boston%20celtics&date=now%201-d&cmpt=q&tz=Etc%2FGMT-1&tz=Etc%2FGMT-1&content=1&cid=RISING_ENTITIES_0_0&cat=0-20) and after a few times try, I got
'You have reached your quota limit. Please try again later'
Are there any methods to deal with the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393969/google-trends-quota-limit

Comment: login and then crawl data , it works.reference:https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/blob/master/pytrends/pyGTrends.py . the _connect and_init_ show how to login in google

Answer (score 0):

login and then crawl data , it wordks.reference:https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/blob/master/pytrends/pyGTrends.py . the _connect and_init_ show how to login in google.